# What is the meaning of check for this.length into a function?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, this, reduce

I'm following an online course about [Javascript Functional Programming](http://reactivex.io/learnrx/)
at the Exercise 16 it show you how reduce is actually implemented, in order to help you understand how to use it, but into this implementation there is something i don't actually get, i'll show the code:

```js
Array.prototype.reduce = function(combiner, initialValue) {
 var counter, accumulatedValue;

 // If the array is empty, do nothing
 if (this.length === 0) {
  return this;
 }
 else {
  // If the user didn't pass an initial value, use the first item.
  if (arguments.length === 1) {
   counter = 1;
   accumulatedValue = this[0];
  }
  else if (arguments.length >= 2) {
   counter = 0;
   accumulatedValue = initialValue;
  }
  else {
   throw "Invalid arguments.";
  }

  // Loop through the array, feeding the current value and the result of
  // the previous computation back into the combiner function until
  // we've exhausted the entire array and are left with only one value.
  while(counter < this.length) {
   accumulatedValue = combiner(accumulatedValue, this[counter])
   counter++;
  }

  return [accumulatedValue];
 }
};
```

I don't understand the first if statement, when it check for `this.length` what this actually mean?

> Take note this is different from the reduce in ES5, which returns an value instead of an Array, this is used just as a sample for the learning purpose.

Comment: `this` is an array.  You need to learn how prototypes work.

Comment: It is just saying that if **this** (which is the array itself) has a length of 0 (which means that there is nothing in it), then it should just return itself. It prevents any of the rest of the code from executing. there is no need to continue, because there is nothing to do to "reduce" it.

Comment: Please find a better tutorial - that's an incorrect implementation of `.reduce` - it should throw an error if the array is empty (and no initial value was provided).   See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: Reduce doesn't wrap the accumulator in an array either.

Comment: @Alnitak actually the tutorial is pretty old i guess, but it say that is not the real implementation of reduce but just a sample used to understand how it have to work.

Comment: Yes, I've just looked at it.  IMHO, you'd be better off just studying the `Array.prototype` functions as documented on MDN.    The author's approach to introducing `.map` and `.filter` is broken.  Also you absolutely must *NOT* overwrite the standard `.reduce` function with that version!

Comment: @Alnitak i will not overwrite any of this functions, it use to understand how to use it in the real world. Anyway i get your point.

Comment: @StefanoSaitta the original code does just that - it says `Array.prototype.reduce = ..`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Array.prototype.reduce = function(...
```

is saying, "create a function on the prototype of Array" - this means that the new `reduce` function will be callable on all arrays, eg:

```
[1, 2, 3].reduce(...
```

This means you can also call it on empty arrays, eg:

```
[].reduce(...
```

Building on the comment:

> If the array is empty, do nothing

You're working on an array, and when the function is called, `this` is set to the array that `reduce` was called on.  This implementation of `reduce` assumes that if that array is empty (ie `this.length === 0`), you can't logically reduce it any further - there's nothing to reduce, so you can return the same empty array.

---

As pointed out by @Alnitak in the comments, this implementation of `reduce` is flawed as compared to [the specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.21).  A different implementation is available on [the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Polyfill) for polyfilling older browsers.

Comment: `.reduce` on an empty array should return the initial value, not itself (or throw an error if there's no initial value) - see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: @Alnitak Thanks - have added a footnote.

Comment: I like this explanation, it's pretty clear, could you please provide me an example of when the if statement will be evaluated to true and when it will be evaluated to false ?

Comment: @StefanoSaitta The first example in my answer would result in `false` - `[1,2,3].reduce(...` - in this case the length is 3.

Comment: Ok now i get it, Thank you for the answer, i guess i have to study a little bit more how prototype work.